# Configure Apache with a htaccess file to strip out unneeded respond-headers

Tags: apache-2.2, http-headers

For ultimate speed, I want my Apache server strip unneeded headers from the response.
Currently, the headers looks like this (excluding the status header):

```
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:200
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Sat, 15 May 2010 16:28:37 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Server:Apache/2.2.14 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.14 OpenSSL/0.9.8l DAV/2 PHP/5.3.1 Phusion_Passenger/2.2.7
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.3.1
```

Which I want to be like:

```
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Type:text/html
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
```

I tried this:

```
Header unset Date
Header unset Server
Header unset X-Powered-By
Header unset Content-Length
Header unset X-Pad
```

But the `server` and `date` and `content-length` headers are still being sent.

How can I configure this in a `.htaccess` file? Thanks

Comment: In what way would that improve what kind of performance?

Comment: @andol It's not much, but it uses less bandwith.

Comment: Yes, and in relation to the actual content you are serving?

Answer (score 1):

you could set `ServerSignature Off` and potentially avoid /that/ particular line.

and `expose_php = Off` in your php.ini to remove that line.

Answer (score 0):

`Date` is required in HTTP/1.1.

You also can't remove `Content-Length` without switching to chunked transfer encoding or downgrading to HTTP/1.0 without keep-alive (but that's opposite of "ultimate speed").